# s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'xs:type' cannot appear in element 'element'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
  <xs:element name="mobilestore">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="mobile" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="brand" xs:type="string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="os" xs:type="string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="model" xs:type="string"></xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ram" xs:type="string"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

> s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'xs:type' cannot appear in element 'element'. false in this uploaded cod

Comment: I've added your XSD as text to your question in place of the image.  In the future, please use text for code, XML, XSD, etc.  Text (formatted as code) is prefered over images because it is easier to search and copy-paste.  Note also that you 
can use the [edit] link to adjust your question after you initially post it.  Thank you.

Comment: yeah thank you for sure i will take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While XSD elements are in the `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` (as you have in your XSD), ***attributes are generally in no namespace.***

So change every occurrence of

```
xs:type="string"
```

to

```
type="xs:string"
```

and your error will go away.